# plt.annotate(Text, (x, y*1,05)) only seems to apply to first text element

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot a bar diagram and the plt.annotate function to display text above each bar. To ensure readibility, I have altered the y-coordinate within plt.annotate to offset the text from the top of the bar. However, this offset only seems to be applied to the first text element.
Here is my code:

```
#create bar plot of population per cluster with percentage reading on top
population_pct = population.div(population.sum(1), axis = 0)
ax = population_new.plot(kind='bar', x="Cluster", y="Occurence", xlabel="Cluster ID", figsize=(16,4), ylabel="Occurence [%]", width = 0.8, color = colors, edgecolor = None)
for p in ax.patches:
    width =p.get_width()
    height = p.get_height()
    x,y = p.get_xy()
    ax.annotate(f'{height} %', (x+ width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting bar-chart:
[image: Bar chart with offset text]

Does anyone know what is happening or am I just no seeing the difference?

Comment: Side note: you might consider upgrading matplotlib and using `bar_label`.

Comment: This approach creates a distance between bar and label that depends on the height of the bar, and this is what you see. Any chance following BigBen's advice?

Comment: @Mr.T is right. Instead of putting the label 2% above the original y, you could offset it by a fixed amount, like `y + height + 1`, which is approximately the offset of the first bar.

Comment: Thank you all! That was quite stupid by me. Will use @gmolnar approach and for future project also update matplotlib @BigBen!